# Настроить скрипт ротации картинок

Tags: скрипт, html, изображения, javascript

Здарвствуйте, пользователи.

Вообщем _http://testing.red-shadow.ru/начало.html скрипт отображается не правильно, коды:

```
 <div class="rotator">
         <ul>
             <li class="show"><a href="http://пневматика.выбирайте.рф">
                 <img src="images/index_img/pne_1.jpg"
 alt="pic1" />
             </a></li>
             <li><a href="http://пневматика.выбирайте.рф">
                 <img src="images/index_img/pne_2.jpg"
 alt="pic2" />
             </a></li>
             <li><a href="http://пневматика.выбирайте.рф">
                 <img src="images/index_img/pne_3.jpg"
 alt="pic3" />
             </a></li>
             <li><a href="http://пневматика.выбирайте.рф">
                 <img src="images/index_img/pne_4.jpg"
 alt="pic4" />
             </a></li>
         </ul>
     </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">

         function theRotator() {            
             $('div.rotator ul li').css({ opacity: 0.0 });

             $('div.rotator ul li:first').css({ opacity: 1.0 });
             setInterval('rotate()', 3000);
         }

         function rotate() {            
             var current = ($('div.rotator ul li.show') ?
 $('div.rotator ul li.show') :
 $('div.rotator ul li:first'));
             if (current.length == 0) current = $('div.rotator ul
 li:first');            
             var next = ((current.next().length) ?
 ((current.next().hasClass('show')) ?
 $('div.rotator ul li:first') :
 current.next()) : $('div.rotator ul
 li:first'));            
             next.css({ opacity: 0.0 })     .addClass('show')   .animate({
 opacity: 1.0 }, 1000);            
             current.animate({ opacity: 0.0 }, 1000)    .removeClass('show');
         };
         $(document).ready(function () {
             //Load the slideshow
             theRotator();
             $('div.rotator').fadeIn(1000);
             $('div.rotator ul li').fadeIn(1000); // tweek for IE
         });
     </script>
```

Comment: а что неправильного-то? все выводится, все отображается, все меняется... мы академиев телепатиии не кончали...

Comment: Смена происходит только у первого ротатора нормально, после цикла ротации второй и третий больше не меняются, а еще по началу показывается только первый